# Clasp - Use environment variable secrets in Typescript for Google Apps Script development

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, clasp

Is there an easy way to not hard-code secrets inside a Google Apps Script project?

I'm using clasp and developing in Typescript as [described in this guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp).

Currently, my script (`Main.ts`) would have some hard-coded secret which I don't want in my version control, and ideally could be swapped out based on some environment variable.

Comment: Have you tried using the usual `dotenv.config()`?

Comment: `dotenv` isn't supported in google apps script context. I guess i'd need to start making a webpack setup...

Answer (score 6):

One approach to keeping secrets out of version control in Google Apps Script is to use the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service):

Store the secret(s) using a function like this

```
function storeSecrets() {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({
        'secret1': 'mySuperSecretPassword',
        'secret2': 'mySecretApiKey',
        // etc...
    })
}
```

You'll have to `clasp push` this and run it just once from the editor (or `clasp run storeSecrets`), then delete the function, *all without committing to version control*.

Once that's done you can access the stored secrets from your code with, e.g.

```
let apiKey = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('secret2')
```

Note that the secrets will still be accessible to anyone with edit access to your project; this workflow just keeps them from getting committed to version control.

Comment: great idea! thanks so much!

Comment: This is a great solution and I'm honestly surprised GAS supports this! Heads up that at the time I'm posting this you don't need to do the hack with creating a function, if you go to wherever your script lives on the Google/GUI side, look for the gear icon on the left to access Project Settings and you can add Script Properties from there, similar to how you'd add environment variables in a typical web hosting platform.

Comment: @JadenRose Yes, good point and it prevents ever writing those secrets in the code at all. But note that the UI only shows a limited number of script properties so if you have a lot of them (I often do!) it may be necessary to manage them programmatically.

Comment: I also note that you could keep your `storeSecrets` function(s) in a file that is ignored by version control (e.g. listed in .gitignore), so that you can keep a reference to them organized locally, but not committed to version control.